# Java Applet requires authentication only when IIS is set to require SSL

Tags: java, ssl, iis, applet

We have a web app running on IIS, there is sensitive information so we are requiring SSL. The web app uses a java applet to digitally sign a pdf.

When we turn off SSL the applet runs fine, when SSL is on this error occurs https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tJ11.jpg

We have a valid SSL certificate applied also.

Please let me know if there is any information I need to add, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of messing around with Authentication settings on IIS we found the problem. For our specific application we needed to turn the site authentication to Windows while setting the WebResource.axd and a few folders pertaining to the applet to Anonymous.

If anyone else is having this issue mess around with the IIS authentication settings as there is probably something your applet is trying to access as Anonymous and cannot.